# Calculate angle between two points relative to the Y-Axis

Tags: c#, angle

In C#, how do I calculate the angle between two points given x1, y1, x2, y2 relative to the Y-axis (assuming that x increases from left to right and y increases from top to bottom)?

Comment: The same way as you do it with pencil and paper, or any other language.

Comment: Math.Atan2(y2-y1, x2-x1)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
static double GetAngle(double x1, double y1, double x2, double y2)
{
    var w = x2 - x1;
    var h = y2 - y1;

    var atan = Math.Atan(h/w) / Math.PI * 180;
    if (w < 0 || h < 0)
        atan += 180;
    if (w > 0 && h < 0)
        atan -= 180;
    if (atan < 0)
        atan += 360;

    return atan % 360;
}
```

[Demo](http://dotnetfiddle.net/ZwCitO)

Comment: Does not return the correct answer, for line: (1,1) (2,3) should return angle ~63.4. returns: 153.4

Comment: @ZiviMagic, you are right. I've updated the answer.